# Execute stored procedure with variables from a variable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a master stored procedure that takes a variable that has the stored procedure name and maybe some variables and executes it.

Currently what I have for the master stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MasterExecute]
      @SP varchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    exec @SP
END
```

Now this works for stored procedures that don't have variables and all I have to give it is the stored procedure name `[dbo].[NoVarSP]`. My problem is when I want to try and give it a stored procedure name and variables, `[dbo].[varSP] @Var1 = '1/1/2017', @Var2 = '1/1/2018'`,  that MasterExecute fails.

Comment: This screams of a horrible design. And it is wide open to sql injection. You don't want to do this. Your execution plan is going to be wrong almost every time this runs. You have created the sql equivalent of a generic class that can do anything. This is sort of like creating a method in .NET named Run that receives the dotnet code as a parameter and runs it.

Comment: Agree with @SeanLange. What is your reasoning for trying to do it this way?

Comment: There are some protections against sql injection but you're not wrong but I am at the end of my rope with an inherited project that would take way more time to break and rebuild than I have.

Comment: Inherited project? Sounds old. Change is welcomed for the latest technology and your expertise.

Comment: Well I would argue that this needs to be thrown away and complete rethought. It is vulnerable to sql injection, it is a performance timebomb, it is a maintenance nightmare. The list of things could go on and on. I feel your pain about a poor design in an inherited system but adding parameters to this is band aid to a bad situation.